# Associating custom model with Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to add `Service` category, same like `Spree::Product`, for that I have to define some associations, as below

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :images, -> { order(:position) }, as: :viewable, class_name: "Spree::Image", dependent: :destroy

      has_many :taxons, class_name: "Spree::Taxon", dependent: :destroy

      validates :name, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 5 }

end
```

Now, first, is this the right method to define such category or should i use some other convention to define `Service`, and for `:taxons` association, should I define migration to add `service_id` column in `spree_taxons` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a new join model such as `ServiceTaxons` instead of adding a `service_id` to `Spree::Taxon`. If you look at how `Products` are linked to `Taxons` it's through the `spree_product_taxons` table.

The more important part is whether or not you need a new `Service` class. You would be better off having your services as just products. Products are deeply ingrained into the Spree system that you are creating a lot of work for yourself trying to implement another model that exists side-by-side with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a matter of design there, **Spree** uses a model to join **Taxons** and **Products**, you should create it and name it services_taxon, the migration should look something like this:

```rb
class CreateServiceTaxon < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :service_taxon do |t|
      t.integer :service_id
      t.integer :taxon_id
    end
  end
end
```

And on the Service model you should add:

```js
class ServiceTaxon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service, :class_name => 'Service', :foreign_key => 'service_id'
  belongs_to :taxon, :class_name => 'Spree::Taxon', :foreign_key => 'taxon_id'
end
```

Another thing i should point out is that if you need some functionality that is already created by the spree team on the product model, you should really consider using theirs, or at least try to extend the product model.